# simple program c++ switch statement to find the employee salaries

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int salary;
    float deduction,netpayable;
    switch(salary/10000){
        cout<<"enter salary amount :";
        cin>>salary;
        case 0:     
        deduction=0;
        netpayable = salary;
        cout<<"netpayable salary is salary-deduction ="<<netpayable;
        break;

        case 1:     
        deduction=1000;
        netpayable = salary-deduction;
        cout<<"netpayable salary is salary-deduction ="<<netpayable;
        break;

        default:    
        deduction=salary*(7/100);
        netpayable = salary-deduction;
        cout<<"netpayable salary is salary-deduction ="<<netpayable;
        break;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

[image: as image is shown no errors have been detected but its not giving the required out]

i have employs and i want to make a simple program in which i am using switch statement to deduct the salary of different employees whom having above 10,000Rs so on... but compiler have shown no error however program is not running and giving a output as shown in image i am little confuse in it.

Comment: The warning message you should be seeing.. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mr5zv3DchszVMB3T

Comment: what is  netpayable = salary-deduction; what is salary-deduction?

Comment: @shami that must be `salary` *minus* `deduction`

Comment: Obviously programming C++ is awesome, but if this is something you want to do regularly and in bulk for your payroll you probably want to use a spreadsheet instead, and you'll get lots of other stuff (e.g. adding up the total net payable for all employees) more or less for free. Or chances are there are cheap or free payroll packages you can use which will do things like prepare payslips, total up how much tax you need to return to the tax authorities too - it's safest to use someone else's well-tested and supported package for this sort of thing.

Comment: just take salary from user and do switch on salary only.

Comment: Never show output in the form of images. It is better to paste it as text instead.

Comment: Also I think it would be simpler to rewrite your switch as `if (salary < 10000) { ... } else if (salary < 20000) { ... } else { ... }` - I see no reason to use a switch here and IMO it just makes it harder to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

You have added a `switch` on `salary` without giving any value to the variable. This results in `salary` having a garbage value.

Just put these lines outside `switch`:

```
cout<<"enter salary amount :";
cin>>salary;

// now start the switch statement here:
switch(...)
{
     ....
}
```

This way, you are first prompting the user to enter the `salary`, and later doing desired operations on it.

Comment: @RaheelAlmis why are you disappointed? Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: my reputation is below 15 so i can not =) sorry about it.

Comment: It does not depend upon reputation. You can accept any answer on a question you have asked.

Answer (score 2):

I see 3 errors in your code. I corrected your code and wrote comments to highlight them.

Please see below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    // 1) Declare all variables of same type to avoid implicit casting errors.
    // In this case we need float or double types.
    float salary;
    float deduction;
    float netpayable;

    // 2) This block must be out of switch instruction!
    cout<<"enter salary amount :";
    cin>>salary;

    // 1.1) The switch will do the expected job
    // only if it works on a int variable, so I put an explicit cast 
    // to (int).
    switch((int)(salary/10000)){

    case 0:     
        deduction=0;
        netpayable = salary;
        cout<<"netpayable salary is salary-deduction ="<<netpayable;
        break;

    case 1:     
        deduction=1000;
        netpayable = salary-deduction;
        cout<<"netpayable salary is salary-deduction ="<<netpayable;
        break;

    default:
        // 3) (7/100) = 0 because compiler interprets it as integer.
        // Use (7./100.) instead.
        deduction=salary*(7./100.);
        netpayable = salary-deduction;
        cout<<"netpayable salary is salary-deduction ="<<netpayable;
        break;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```